# Can I get a SSL certificate for my domain name from Apple

Tags: developer-program

I have bought an Apple developer subscription. I've developed a small Safari extension. To publish it in the extension gallery it should be hosted at a web server. I leased a domain name and a virtual private server. Hosted a web server. Apple has given me a certificate to sign the Safari extension. Can I also get a SSL certificate for my domain name from Apple? After all I have an Apple developer subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Apple does not issue SSL/TLS certificates for web hosting purposes. Apple's developer certificates are for code signing only.

## LetsEncrypt and Caddy Server

[LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) provide free SSL/TLS certificates for use with your web site.

To ease the management your web site, consider [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com) for your web server. Caddy handles the certificate provisioning and renewal for you.

For non-commercial use, [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com), also offer free certificates.